Transferring Data between userforms using the .Tag Property
So I have a few Userforms (Let´s call them UserformA1, UserformA2,) etc. that should all lead into one UserformB. Ideally, when clicking a commandbutton1, Userform B open and some textbox values need are transferred from whichever UserformA is open to the same text boxes in Userform B. I have been attempting to use the tag property to determine which userform A was open, without much success, as it remains empty (tested that using a msgBox)
Here´s the code in UserformA1
Private Sub CmdButton_Click()
UserformB.Tag = "UserformA1"
UserformB.Show

And the code to receive the Tag Property in Userform B
Private Sub UserForm_Initalize()
Origin = Me.Tag
Select Case Origin
Case "UserformA1"
Me.Textbox1.Value = UserformA1.Textbox1.Value
Case "UserformA2"
Me.Textbox1.Value = UserformA1.Textbox1.Value
End Case
End Sub


You should instantiate instances of the userforms instead of using the default instance.  Read: UserForm1.Show

There are a number of ways to accomplish what you need.  One simple way is like this, which also does not use the default instance of the UserForm:
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdButton_Click()
   Dim ufb As UserFormB
   
   Set ufb = New UserFormB
   ufb.TextBox1.Text = Me.TextBox1.Text
   ufb.Show
End Sub

